# Finding a,b,c of a quadratic equation for curves, tangents, and normals

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Question: The curve $y=ax^2+bx+c$ passes through the points $A(-2,0)$ and $B(3,20)$. The slope of the normal at $A$ is $1$, and the gradient of the tangent at $B$ is $9$. Find the values of $a$, $b$, and $c$.

After a few attempts, I managed to get $3$ simultaneous equations with $4a-2b+c=0$, $-2a-b=-1$, and $2a+b=1$. I'm pretty sure they are not correct because they cannot be solved using matrices and I'm having a hard time solving them. Please help me with this problem!

Note: I'm sorry but I do not know how to use MathJax.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

By normal, $$-1=2a(-1)+b$$

By tangent, $$9=2a(3)+b$$

Solve for $a,b$

$c$ can be derived using the equation you have reached at.

Comment: I solved using matrices, now I have $a=1.25$, $b=1.5$, and $c=-2$. When I plugged in for $x=3$, $y$ did not come out as $20$. What have I done wrong?

Comment: The slope of the normal at $(-2,0)$ should give the equation $-1=-4a+b.$

Answer (score 0):

We translate the given conditions to equations on $a,b,c:$

- $A$ belongs to the curve if and only if $4a-2b+c=0.$
- $B$ belongs to the curve if and only if $9a+3b+c=0.$
- The slope of the tangent at $B$ is $9$ if and only if $6a+b=9.$
- The slope of the normal at $A$ is $1$ if and only if $\dfrac{-1}{-4a+b}=1.$

(Note that the slope of the tangent line at $x=x_0$ is $y'(x_0)=2ax_0+b$ and the slope of the normal line is $\dfrac{-1}{y'(x_0)}=\dfrac{-1}{2ax_0+b}$.)

Solving the equations we get $a=1,b=3,c=2.$